# Segmentation Fault: 11 doing anything with node

Tags: c++, c, node.js

This question appears to have been asked a lot but most appear to be directly related to `C` development.

I am/have been doing a lot of Node dev lately and I have run into this error `Segmentation Fault: 11`. After reading most if not all the questions here on StackOverflow and their respective answers, this leads me back to the beginning...

Here is what I know:

- This happens when I run something simple like `npm start` on most but *not all* projects
- This happens with build systems such as `gulp` and `grunt`
- This error does not appear to happen on my co-workers machines
- I know from general research this appears to be a memory problem

  - When I run from `iTerm` I get it as well as when I run from within say `Webstorm`
  - I have 16 gb of ram and I run `iStats` and I dont see any up tick in memory usage when I get this error.

I use `nvm` and I have hoped to different versions of the node runtime but it seems to happen across all of them.

I have completely nuked node and nvm in hopes that would fix it but alas it did not.

Are there any other tricks or tips?

Comment: Deleting the `node_modules` directory and reinstalling the dependencies using `npm install` on the projects where you get this could help. I have noticed that some native modules (that gets built using node-gyp on install) tends to give this error after a node upgrade.

Comment: A "flawed Javascript interpreter" could be a dynamically linked one built against a different version of one or more native components than the ones presented to it a run time.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger I am aware this is not a javascript problem. Why the snarkiness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been seen a lot recently as people update to Node 4.x. Compiled add-ons need to be rebuilt.

The fast and easy thing to try is running `npm rebuild` on your project.

If that doesn't work, try removing the `node_modules` directory and then running `npm install`.

And if that doesn't work, either your project or a dependency has code interacting with native stuff that needs to be updated. The easiest thing to do in that case might be to go back to the previous version of Node. (But the best thing to do would be to update your project and/or submit pull requests for its dependencies to fix them. You can find out some more details at [the NAN repo](https://github.com/nodejs/nan).)